# How to use document and window element in react.js

Tags: reactjs, dom, client-side

I am trying to render a npm package plugin "react-share" inside an existing next.js / react.js app. However the plugin makes use of elements rendered on the client:

```
ReactDOM.render(<ShareButtons />, document.querySelector('#content'));
```

and window in:

```
  <PinterestShareButton
    url={String(window.location)}
    media={`${String(window.location)}/${exampleImage}`}
    windowWidth={1000}
    windowHeight={730}
    className="Demo__some-network__share-button">
    <PinterestIcon size={32} round />
  </PinterestShareButton>
```

I can find any simple workarounds to this, have I missed something?

Lilian

Comment: Are you getting any errors? React **is** javascript, so there shouldn't be any issue using `document` and `window` in your code.

Comment: This describes various ways https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2473

Comment: Yes, the errors are: ` document.queryselector react.js "document is not defined"`

Comment: @HGB are you using any type checker like `flow` ?

Comment: I think @arpl link might have the answer, but with next.js you can only use the window object inside of componentDidMount.

Comment: Do you have an example @tay

Comment: @Aaqib I am not using a type checker, I am just getting the not defined errors as a result of it not being rendered isomorphically and don't know how to do this. `Next.js` uses `./pages/`as the default files directory and `index` is a `js` file.